# Python-loop to plot only categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib, graph

I have a dataset that contains a lot of categorical variables which I would like to plot in a scatter graph without having to encode the variables.
This is my attempt:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 9))

    for column in df:

     if df[column].dtype != np.int64 and df[column].dtype != np.float64:

        ca = df.plot.scatter(x=df[column],y= df['log_prices'], ax = 

        fig.add_subplot(2,3,df[column]+1))

        plt.plot(df.iloc[:,df[column]].values, sm.OLS(df.iloc
        [:,df['log_prices'].values,sm.add_constant(df.iloc[:,df[column]].values)).fit().fittedvalues,'r-')
```

This is the error I'm getting at the moment:

```
     ----> 5             ca = df.plot.scatter(x=df[column],y=df['log_prices'], ax = fig.add_subplot(2,3,df_061[column]+1))

         cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

This has clearly something to do with log_prices.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, you can skip looping and use the built-in `select_dtypes` function in pandas, which is [just great](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) IMO

Answer (score 1):

```
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

categorical=[]
for column in df:
    if is_string_dtype(df[column]):
        categorical.append(column)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(20, 10))
for variable, subplot in zip(categorical, ax.flatten()):
    sns.countplot(df_2[variable], ax=subplot)
    for label in subplot.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)
```

Comment: df_2 needsd to be changed to df

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making the following change:

```
ca = df.plot.scatter(x = column, y = 'log_prices', ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, df[column] + 1))
```

When using the `df.plot()` method, you need to provide the column names to the x and y arguments, not the actual data. The data already resides in `df`, so you just need to give it the columns to use.

Here is a partial replication of your code using example data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns = ['A','B','C','D','E'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 9))

idx = 0

for column in df:

#    if df[column].dtype != np.int64 and df[column].dtype != np.float64:
    idx += 1
    ca = df.plot.scatter(x = column, y = 'A', ax = fig.add_subplot(2,3,idx))

#    plt.plot(df.iloc[:,df[column]].values, sm.OLS(df.iloc[:,df['log_prices'].values,sm.add_constant(df.iloc[:,df[column]].values)).fit().fittedvalues,'r-')
```

This code produces the following plot:
[image: Subplots]

Comment: I now just get this: 
                  <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x115ff780>, but not an actual graph

Comment: Without having your data, it is difficult to test everything at once. There may be some improvements needed in the second plotting line as well. Perhaps a call of plt.show() might also be needed.

Comment: @J.DF ... be sure to show plot at the end: `plt.show()` (and even close it `plt.clf()`, `plt.close()`).

Comment: Thanks. I see you've commented out the if statement for columns containing categorical variables only. However, that's what I'm having trouble with. What's the best way plot categorical variables only?